# AS3 - Pausing on loss of focus

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, focus

I'm working on a Flash mobile game. If the app loses focus (a call comes in for example) I need the game timer to stop until focus is restored. Here is my current code but I'm getting a "Argument count mismatch error" onDeactivate(). Expected 0, got 1.

Here is the related code, I think:

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);
addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE,onDeactivate);

public function onActivate():void {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showTime);
}

public function onDeactivate():void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showTime);
}
```

I'm getting the error when testing in flash and I close the window. What am I missing? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You missed out the event argument, your event handlers should look like: `public function onActivate(e:Event):void {}` and `public function onDeactivate(e:Event):void {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onActivate and onDeactivate are event listeners. This means they will be called with event argument. Give them one like this: `onDeactivate(event:Event):void`.

Comment: And if you get no errors with onActivate, this only means it isn't called :)

Comment: I think the correct term is event handlers as they handle events, not a big deal though, am just a terminology buff.

Comment: Works. Thanks. Thought I had tried something like that already but guess not.